# How can I get the value of h as Int?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting two different answers, when running this line of code:

```
h = (1 + math.floor(((26*(m + 1))/10)) + k + math.floor(k / 4) + math.floor(j / 4) + (5 * j)) % 7
```

When run in IDLE directly, I get `6`, but when I run it as a script, I get `6.8`. I want value of `h` as an `int`. When I am printing it in the program it is giving me `float` value.

```
def getStartDay(year, month):
    m = month
    if m == 1:
        month = 12
        year = year -1
    if m == 2:
        month = 14
        year = year -1
    j = year / 100
    k = year % 100

    # Zeller's congruence
    h = (1 + math.floor(((26*(4 + 1))/10)) + 16 + math.floor(16 / 4) + math.floor(20 / 4) + (5 * 20)) % 7
    print(h)
    return h
```

Comment: Perhaps your IDLE is using Python 2?

Comment: I'd guess that when you're running your program as a script, you're using a different version of Python than when you're running with IDLE. I'm not sure how you'd get `6.8` (rather than `6.0`) in either version though, since you have all those `floor` calls scattered around. I suggest using the `//` operator instead of `/` and staying with integers the whole time.

Comment: python 2.x handles integer division differently than in python 3, maybe your script is using a different version of python than IDLE. in python 2.x: 5/3 == 1, in python 3: 5/3==1.666666

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the issue (float instead of int) is that the `floor` function behaves differently in python 2 and 3

Python 2 gives float

```
>>> math.floor(4)
4.0
```

Whereas Python 3 returns int

```
>>> math.floor(4)
4
```

I coudld not reproduce 6.8 for h. I could however reproduce the 6.0 vs 6, so the issue can probabbly be resolved by returning 'int(h)'

```
return int(h)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use `int()` :)

```
print(int(6.8))
>>> 6
```

Your code "fixed":

```
def getStartDay(year, month):
    #Don't forget to import math! and try "import antigravity" :)
    m = month
    if m == 1:
        month = 12
        year = year -1
    if m == 2:
        month = 14
        year = year -1
    j = year / 100
    k = year % 100

    # Zeller's congruence (made it shorter, >80 character lines are
    #                      considered bad formatted code .-.)
    h = (1 + math.floor(((26*(4 + 1))/10)) + 16 + math.floor(16 / 4)
         + math.floor(20 / 4) + (5 * 20)) % 7
    h = int(h)
    print(h)
    return h
```